# Will a recursive 'setTimeout' function call eventually kill the JS Engine?

Tags: javascript, recursion, settimeout

Let's say I have some data that I need to get from the server about every 10 seconds.  I would have a function that gets the data via AJAX and then call setTimeout to call this function again:

```
function GetData(){
   $.ajax({
       url: "data.json",
       dataType: "json",
       success: function(data){
         // do somthing with the data

         setTimeout(GetData, 10000);
      },
      error: function(){
         setTimeout(GetData, 10000);
      }
   });
}
```

If someone leaves the web page open all day, it could get thousands of recursive function calls.

I don't want to use setInterval because that does not take into account network delay.  If the network is busy and it takes 15 seconds to process the request, I don't want to ask it again before I get the AJAX timeout.

What is the best way to handle a function that needs to be called periodically?

Comment: Each subsequent call to GetData will be completely independent of each other. After any given GetData execution run completes, its context will be destroyed, and a new one created when the timer expires.

Comment: this would probably cause trouble for the server well before the client-side javascript. as the others have mentioned, you don't have a call stack issue because the setTimeout allows the function to return and be removed from the stack. Recursion algorithmically, but not actually.

Comment: This question is exactly what I am researching. Thanks for bring it here.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

There's no actual recursion because the call to GetData is delayed and the JavaScript context is destroyed in the meantime. So it won't crash the JS engine.

For your code sample, this is basically what will happen at the JS engine level:

1. Initialize JS engine
2. Create GetData function context
3. Execute GetData statements including "setTimeOut"
4. "setTimeOut" instruct the JS engine to call a function in 10 seconds
5. Destroy GetData function context
6. At this point, in terms of memory use, we are back to step 1. The only difference is that the JS engine stored a reference to a function and when to call it (lets call this data "futureCall").
7. After 10 seconds, repeat from step 2. "futureCall" is destroyed.

Comment: Is this implementation dependent?  Or is this in the spec of JavaScript?

Comment: There's noting in the spec that says "never destroy a context from which setTimeout has been called". It's not a recursion, so there's no reason any implementation would fail, even badly coded ones.

Comment: I'm still wrapping my head around this...  So if I assume everything in JS is run as an event handler, then the setTimeout just triggers another event to be handled.  It gets its own stack/thread/process/memory/everything.

Comment: Yes pretty much. Basically, once GetData has been executed, its context is destroyed. The only thing that the JS engine kept is the name of the timeout function and when to call it. I've updated my post with the steps the JS engine go through to run your sample. Hope it makes sense.

Comment: @this.lau_ What would happen (in terms of call stack, not eventual out of memory error) if GetData was accepting parameters and local parameters were passed to it when calling setTimeout? For example like this Gist: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/1769420ad62c1d5d9d82 As the invoked function references local variables of the parent function, wouldn't it require a call stack to be maintained?