# Does Javascript's setInterval block for function return?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, browser

I have a javascript function `function a()` that I want to be executed every 10 seconds.
I found that I can use the `setInterval` so that I can do something like: `setInverval(a, 10000);`
My question is the following:
Does this mean that
i) every 10 seconds the specified function is called (regardless if the previous execution is running/multithreaded way) OR
ii) that the function is called and when this function *has finished execution* then the next call of the function is scheduled after 10 seconds?
I am basically interested in option 2. If option 1 is what is happening by default then how could I achieve option 2?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Basically, `setInterval` runs according to option 1, except that if the function takes more than the interval time, it will not be fired again until it has finished and reached the next tick. For example, if you have an interval of 1 second and your function takes 1.5 seconds, it will run on the 2 second tick.

If you want the behaviour of option 2 (run X seconds after function completion), call `setTimeout` at the completion of your function instead:

```
setTimeout(function a() {
    // your own code
    setTimeout(a, 1000);
}, 1000);
```

How this works is that it first waits 1 second, then calls the function passed to `setTimeout`. At the end of the function, the function itself (`a` is the name of the function) is passed to `setTimeout`, which then waits another second to call the function again. This continues until JavaScript execution is halted or the timeout is removed by using `clearTimeout`.

Note that even if you use `setInterval`, the function will *never* be run concurrently, due to JavaScript's single-threaded nature.

Comment: 1) Basically I am interested in making sure that no instances of my function are running concurrently but all function calls are serial. 2) How does this recursive timeout work?

Comment: Does @lanzz say the oposite?

Comment: @Jim: not, lanzz is not saying the opposite thing. If the function takes 0.5 seconds and the interval is 1 second, the function will still be called every second. If you use the `setTimeout` method, it would be called every 1.5 seconds. By the way, JavaScript isn't multi-threaded, except if you use web workers which run in a separate context (does not apply to your situation).

Comment: So basically how exactly does the recursive timeout snippet work?

Comment: Ok, I see what you mean.But it seems to me that this would lead to stack overflow due to too many recursions. Unless I somehow incorporate in the logic of this, a way to stop recursing.

Comment: @Jim: that's because `setTimeout` is asynchronous, which means that `setTimeout` returns before the function passed is called. It's [not actually recursion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6779586/will-a-recursive-settimeout-function-call-eventually-kill-the-js-engine), sorry for being misleading.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48135/discussion-between-qantas-94-heavy-and-jim)

Comment: To have behaviour 1 you need to setTimeout(func, 0) inside your setInterval.

Answer (score 3):

`setInterval(a, 10000)` schedules a function to be called every 10 seconds, regardless of the time it took its previous invocations to complete. If you want to schedule the next call for 10 seconds after the completion of the last call, you should call `setTimeout(a, 10000)` within the `a` function itself, right before it returns, instead of using `setInterval`.

Comment: Basically I am interested in making sure that no instances of my function are running concurrently but all function calls are serial.I am not clear if they are serial from your answer