# How does javascript setInterval and setTimeout 'threads' works?

Tags: javascript, jquery, settimeout, setinterval, timing

Let's consider such html:

```
<div class="my-class"></div>
```

and js (using `jQuery`):

```
var interval = 10;

setInterval(function(){
    //I toggle .my-class 'extra-class' every 10ms
    $(".my-class").toggleClass("extra-class"); 
}, interval);

//then outside interval I'm doing some action on the same item as interval does
$(".my-class").each(function(){
    var t = $(this).addClass("extra-class"); //I'm sure I've added extra-class

    //but now I'm doing some action longer than 10ms
    for (var i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
        //some long action here that could take more than 10ms
    };

    //can I still be sure now that it have extra-class added in THIS scope
    //it was added in this scope but it is toggled all the time
    console.log( t.hasClass("extra-class") ); 
});
```

What happens is:

- I'm toggling `extra-class` on `.my-class` all the time every `10ms`
- I've got some `scope` when I'm **sure** I've added `extra-class` to some item
- Than in the same `scope` I'm doing some action that takes more time
  than `10ms`
- **Can I be sure now that my item still have class I've added in current
  `scope`?**

---

If I can be sure - does it mean that interval is waiting for my scopes to finish even if more time passed from last interval than it should wait? What if some single scope would take 100x times more than interval time?

If I can't be sure - does it mean that interval actions can be fired in the middle of my scope code?

Comment: Yes. JS is single-threaded, so it runs only one function at a time. It's not possible for a function to run "in the middle" of another one.

Comment: see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21953468/does-javascripts-setinterval-block-for-function-return

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// (A)
var t = $(this).addClass("extra-class"); //I'm sure I've added extra-class

// (B)
// Some long action here that could take more than 10ms
...

// (C)
// can I still be sure now that "this" still has class "extra-class"?
```

Yes. Since JavasScript is single-threaded, there's only one thread that runs through `A`, `B` and then `C`. No other JavaScript code will be executed until the currently executing code has finished.

Even if you have set a `setInterval` in order to execute a function at a given time, that function will only run on time if the single thread is free. Otherwise, it will have to wait until the single thread has finished executing everything else.