# jQuery ajax calls in a loop make browser crash

Tags: jquery, ajax

This is a kinda strange thing and I really thing it's the response time from the database that causes a browser to crash after 10 minutes. In the ajax call all data from a certain table is requested and then parsed in a div. The database table isn't large (yet)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var thisTime = "start";
    doRefresh = function () {
        $.ajax({
            url : "/captainslog/chats/load",
            type: "POST",
            success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                $("#list_chats").html(data);
                setTimeout(doRefresh, 5000);
                if ( thisTime == "start") {
                    $("#list_chats").animate({ scrollTop: $('#list_chats')[0].scrollHeight}, 1000);
                }
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
                console.log('OOPS! Something went wrong');
            }
        });
    }
    setTimeout(doRefresh, 5000);
</script>
```

Comment: Have you debugged your browser and watched what happens? I [don't think anything is inherently wrong](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6779586/will-a-recursive-settimeout-function-call-eventually-kill-the-js-engine)

Comment: Have you tryied with my answer to solve your problem?

Comment: @faby, the $.ajaxSetup({cache:false}); did the trick in this case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be jQuery cache getting too large for memory.

Try setting the cache param off.

```
 $.ajaxSetup({cache:false});
```

Comment: First, it's a post request, it's not cached. Second, it's the *same URL* every request, so even if it were cached, it would be one single cached thing that just got served up over and over from cache.