# how toschedule continouesly running function in node js?

Tags: node.js

I would like to schedule a function which will run every 3 seconds until my app exits. I don't use setInterval because If something goes wrong it shouldn't be scheduled anymore so i use setTimeout
i wrote something like this

```
function someWork(){
   setTimeout(function(){
     //do Stuff here
     someWork();
},3000)
}
```

will it cause any memory , or performance leaks. or is there any better solution?

Comment: What about using [`clearInterval()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp) to stop your `setInterval` execution?

Comment: the problem is i don't know how much time takes //do stuff here maybe it will took more than 3 seconds so if i use setInterval it will run this function again while the previous one is not finished so I must be sure that method has been finished

Comment: And can it execute again *before* the 3-second interval, for example as soon as the previous execution is finished, or must it wait *at least* 3 sec and *at most* the duration of the previous execution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, `setTimeout` is the way to go. You can use an external library, like the already mentioned [node-cron](https://github.com/ncb000gt/node-cron) or [agenda](https://github.com/rschmukler/agenda), but those too use `setTimeout` internally, so using one doesn't really make sense if you don't need any of the other features.

You already knew the two pitfalls of `setInterval`:

1. it ignores errors
2. it does not care if the task takes more than the interval to execute

"Recursive" `setTimeout` will not cause memory leaks or stack overflow. See e.g. [Will a recursive 'setTimeout' function call eventually kill the JS Engine?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6779586/3349511)

Answer (score 0):

The best way to automate tasks at backend is to use cron jobs. Here is a module to the rescue [node-cron](https://github.com/ncb000gt/node-cron). Here is an example -

```
var CronJob = require('cron').CronJob;
var job = new CronJob('*/3 * * * * *', function() {
  /*
   * Runs every 3 seconds as long as your server is running
   */
  }, function () {
    /* This function is executed when the job stops */
  },
  true, /* Start the job right now */
  timeZone /* Time zone of this job. */
);
```