# JavaScript setTimeout infinite loop without recursion

Tags: javascript, jquery, settimeout, stack-overflow, obfuscation

I cannot use [Obfuscator.io](https://obfuscator.io/) to uglify my JS script because it contains a `setTimeout` within a function that calls itself.
**MCVE:**

```
function repeater() {
    // DO SOME STUFF...
    setTimeout(repeater, 100);
}
repeater();
```

**Custom obfuscation settings required to reproduce:**
- Identifier Names Generator: <kbd>Mangled</kbd>
- Reserved Names: <kbd>$</kbd> - jQuery

**[Obfuscator.io's](https://obfuscator.io/) error message:**

> Error: @postConstruct error in class t: @postConstruct error in class t: Maximum call stack size exceeded

I've read a few other Stack Overflow questions about this. [I understand that calling `setTimeout(func)` inside `func` is **not** actually recursion.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6779586/will-a-recursive-settimeout-function-call-eventually-kill-the-js-engine)

But still, [Obfuscator.io's](https://obfuscator.io/) algorithm can't handle a self-invoking `setTimeout` delay.

How do I make a repeatedly-executing function using `setTimeout` without calling it in the function itself? **I don't want to use `setInterval` because I want the delay to begin each time after the function's code has run.** [`setInterval` ignores that.](http://reallifejs.com/brainchunks/repeated-events-timeout-or-interval/)

Comment: Inserting the given code on the website does not result in the given error.

Comment: Adding `insert into Obfuscator.io to reproduce issue`  in bold letters does not help. As I said inserting the code into obfuscator.io works well. The result is e.g. `function _0x19c7c5(){setTimeout(_0x19c7c5,0x64);}_0x19c7c5();` , or larger code depending on the settings. But I was not able to find one setting that produces the given error, neither while obfuscating, nor while running the resulting code.

Comment: Tried again with `tranform object keys`... And it still works fine (since there is no object in your code chunk, it's normal to notice no difference).

Comment: Still no difference with the `mangled` option in Identifier Names Generator... Works fine.

Comment: I suppose you try to obfuscate a much complex code chunk... The issue certainly is there. Try to check that code [here](https://www.jslint.com/).

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette Even the simple example in this question causes Obfuscator.io to throw that error.

Comment: If you don't set `$` as reserved name, the Obfuscator.io can obfuscate your code!

Comment: @SallyCJ You have to click the `+` button for the reserved name to be added

Comment: @George thanks for pointing it out. No wonder why I felt like something's not right when I typed '$' into the box.. xD

Comment: I just set your "Custom obfuscation settings required to reproduce" then by default code (Not your code) get some error. So your settings is wrong! No your code.

Comment: what a name you have @clickbait? Why don't you use setInterval() function instead?

Comment: @KiranShakya Last paragraph explains why

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think your issue is actually in the use of

- Reserved Names: <kbd>$</kbd> - jQuery

as using that as the configuration results in this

[image]

Which is what you're getting, if you change it to <kbd>^$</kbd> which is what the text box and description on the website says it should be, your code obfuscates fine

[image]

> **Reserved Names**
>
> Disables obfuscation and generation of identifiers, which being matched by passed RegExp patterns.
>
> For instance, if you add `^someName`, the obfuscator will ensure that all variables, function names and function arguments that starts with someName will not get mangled.

Comment: or use jQuery instead of $ to avoid that confict?

Answer (score 1):

I this you have something like that:

```
function repeater() {
    // DO SOME STUFF...
    const someCodeInJQuery = $('#someId')
    setTimeout(repeater, 100);
}
repeater();
```

Just need change to:

```
function repeater() {
    // DO SOME STUFF...
    const someCodeInJQuery = jQuery('#someId'); // Pay attention here
    setTimeout(repeater, 100);
}
repeater();
```

> Anwer: change $ to jQuery in your code, because obfuscator have
>   reserved words
>
> Reccomendation: the best way - use [uglifyJS](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uglify-js) instead of obfuscator