# too much recursion when wrapping setTimeout() in web worker

Tags: javascript, web-worker

I am trying to wrap the self.setTimeout() function inside a web worker (so there is no native window object). I thought it would be pretty straight forward by using the method apply syntax:

```
window.setTimeout = function ( /**/) {
    return setTimeout.apply(self,arguments); 
};
```

This call should be equivalent to calling self.setTimeout() with any number of arguments (function, delay, arguments to pass to function) and returning the id for the timeout.

However, the middle line of code eventually throws "too much recursion" error. It looks like calling it like this somehow breaks the mechanic described here: [Will a recursive 'setTimeout' function call eventually kill the JS Engine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6779586/will-a-recursive-settimeout-function-call-eventually-kill-the-js-engine) that destroys previous function context and makes it actually recursive. Just in case it is browser specific: Tested in Firefox 74.0 (64-Bit).

**Some background**

Just in case if anyone is wondering, why I am trying this:

I want to move some CPU-heavy code from the main Thread to web-workers without rewriting everything.

Unfortunately, the code relies on some library that in turn relies on window and document being present, or it won't initialize.

As a workaround, I am using [Mock Dom](https://github.com/getify/Mock-DOM-Resources) inside the worker. Because I don't actually want to do DOM manipulations, I am just adding any features missing from the mock dom in the most simply way possible. But for some reason, the library at some point explicitely calls window.setTimeout() instead of just setTimeout() - so I need to add this function to the mock window object and it needs to work correctly.

**Update**

Thx, Alexandre Senges for pointing out the error that this function will actually call itself.

The solution inside a web-Worker that actually works is

```
window.setTimeout = function ( /**/) {
    return DedicatedWorkerGlobalScope.prototype.setTimeout.apply(self,arguments); 
};
```

So, I need to write the whole path of the fuction to prevent window.setTimeout from calling itself.

**Update 2**

Actually, as the other answer from Kaiido pointed out, my original idea should have worked fine on it's own. The reason why too much recursion happened was that I made an error in some other part of the code that effectively copied `self.setTimeout = window.setTimeout` - thus causing `setTimeout===self.setTimeout===window.setTimeout` so the function window.setTimeout suddenly was recursive without intention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code should work just fine:

```js
const worker_script = `
  const window = {};
  window.setTimeout = function ( /**/) {
    return setTimeout.apply(self,arguments); 
  };
  window.setTimeout( (val)=>postMessage('done ' + val), 200, 'ok');
`;
const blob = new Blob( [ worker_script ] );
const url = URL.createObjectURL( blob );
const worker = new Worker( url );
worker.onmessage = e => console.log( e.data );
worker.onerror = console.error;
```

To get this error, you probably did set `window` to `self`:

```js
const worker_script = `
  const window = self;
  window.setTimeout = function ( /**/) {
    return setTimeout.apply(self,arguments); 
  };
  window.setTimeout( (val)=>postMessage('done ' + val), 200, 'ok');
`;
const blob = new Blob( [ worker_script ] );
const url = URL.createObjectURL( blob );
const worker = new Worker( url );
worker.onmessage = e => console.log( e.data );
worker.onerror = console.error;
```

If so, you don't even need to rewrite anything:

```js
const worker_script = `
  const window = self;
  window.setTimeout( (val)=>postMessage('done ' + val), 200, 'ok');
`;
const blob = new Blob( [ worker_script ] );
const url = URL.createObjectURL( blob );
const worker = new Worker( url );
worker.onmessage = e => console.log( e.data );
worker.onerror = console.error;
```

Comment: Hello. Yes this answer makes actually more sense. I could not wrap my head around why my original code should cause an endless recursion loop and just put it to that it probably is due to the interpretative nature of JS and accepted it.
But to clarify: I did not set `window` to `self`, but window is the actually a mock dom window:
`var window = $DOM( {docReadyState:"complete" } );`
But chances are that there is some other part in the code -either my own or library- that will set self.setTimeout = window.setTimeout for some reason.

Comment: your answer is indeed completely correct (given the missing knowledge what some other part of my code might do). I made a tiny little error that did not throw a syntax error. This error caused that the code bit effectively copied ALL members from `window` to `self` - including `setTimeout` - instead of copying every _new_ member that library X injected into `window` to self, what was the intention,

Answer (score 2):

Maximum recursion depth happens when you call the same function over and over again in itself too many times. The reason is that every time you call the function, you have to create new instances of all its stack variables.

For instance:

```
const recursive = (x) => {
    console.log(x);
    recursive(x+1);
}
```

Here, every time the function calls itself, it creates a new x that is pushed to the stack without popping the previous x because we still haven't returned from the caller. If we let that happen for too long, the stack would get full and we would get a `StackOverflow` (thus the name of the website.)

Now, JS protects us from letting that happen by limiting the depth of the call stack.

In your example, the problem is due to the fact that you inadvertently created a recursive function. When you will call your new `window.setTimeout`, it will call `setTimeout.apply` which refers to the new function itself, so it calls itself again etc. One fix would be to extract the previous method in a new variable and call it afterwards:

```
window.oldTimeout = window.setTimeout;
window.setTimeout = function ( /**/) {
    return oldTimeout.apply(self,arguments); 
};
```

However I think that what you are trying to do is all around a bad idea. You shouldn't try to replace a `window` method as it will change it for all your program and even for libraries which might be dependent on them. If I were you, I would simply create a new function `myTimeout`.

Comment: there exists no window.setTimeout before I create it. As said in my first sentence, I am inside a web-worker and web-workers do not have a window object. All globals are part of the DedicatedWorkerGlobalScope type object.so if I simply write setTimeout(), this is actually the setTimeout from the DedicatedWorkerGlobalScope and not window.setTimeout()

Comment: @wulf21 I doesn't make a difference to the fact that it is calling itself. You would have to change to window.setTimeout = () => DedicatedWorkerGlobalScope.setTimeout()...

Comment: @wulf21 I'm not familiar with WebWorkers, but the problem is the same, you call the same function inside itself

Comment: Hi, thanks for the hint. It was enough to find a solution. I'll mark this answer as correct and update my post with how I actually solved it.